# Add table controls with wp_editor minimal editor configuration ('teeny')

Tags: tinymce, editor, wp-editor, table

I want to add the table controls for wp_editor(tinymce) initiated with teeny=>true. Here is what I have done so far (without success):

```
<?php
$tinymce_options = array('plugins' => "table", 'theme_advanced_buttons2' => "tablecontrols");
$editor_config= array('teeny'=>true, 'textarea_rows'=>5, 'editor_class'=>'csec_text', 'textarea_name'=>'csec_text', 'wpautop'=>false, 'tinymce'=>$tinymce_options);
wp_editor($content, $id, $editor_config);
?>
```

Can anyone suggest anything reagrding this? Thanks in advance.

I'm using:

> Wordpress 5.1.1 + TinyMCE advanced 5.1.0

Current output (with requirement):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it running with few pieces of extra buttons too :):

```
<?php
$tinymce_options = array('plugins' => "table,lists,link,textcolor,hr", 'toolbar1'=>"fontsizeselect,forecolor,backcolor,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,alignjustify",'toolbar2'=>"blockquote,hr,table,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link,unlink");
$editor_config= array('teeny'=>true, 'textarea_rows'=>5, 'editor_class'=>'csec_text', 'textarea_name'=>'csec_text', 'wpautop'=>false, 'tinymce'=>$tinymce_options);
wp_editor($content, $id, $editor_config);
?>
```

Check: [wp_editor in add_meta_boxes does not show gallery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/336780/wp-editor-in-add-meta-boxes-does-not-show-gallery/) for better option working in accordance with Wordpress.