# wp_editor in add_meta_boxes does not show gallery

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, metabox, gallery, wp-editor

I have added a meta box in the page edit section:

```
add_meta_box('custom_section_box', 'Sections', array($this, 'section_box'), 'page','normal','high');
```

Within the box, there is a wp_editor call:

```
$tinymce_options = array('plugins' => "table,lists,link,textcolor,hr", 'toolbar1'=>"fontsizeselect,forecolor,backcolor,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,alignjustify",'toolbar2'=>"blockquote,hr,table,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link,unlink");
$editor_config= array('teeny'=>true, 'textarea_rows'=>10, 'editor_class'=>'csec_text', 'textarea_name'=>'csec_body', 'wpautop'=>false, 'tinymce'=>$tinymce_options);
wp_editor(html_entity_decode(stripslashes($vals['content'])), 'csec_body', $editor_config);
```

Everything is working fine, but when I add a gallery through the media button, it displays the gallery shortcode only (like [gallery link="file" ids="759,760,761"]). There is no usual display of the gallery as in the normal page editor with edit/delete buttons.

I had tried to add the **do_shortcode** to pass the value in wp_editor, but that displays the full html instead. Also other shortcodes are rendered as html.

Can you please help?

Comment: Include your w_editor settings `$editor_config` too

Comment: Yes. I did that.
$editor_config= array('teeny'=>true, 'textarea_rows'=>10, 'editor_class'=>'csec_text', 'textarea_name'=>'csec_body', 'wpautop'=>false, 'tinymce'=>$tinymce_options);

Comment: All is working fine except the gallery display.Image edit is also not working too.

Comment: Try to simply call wp_editor without 3 argument - '$editor_config'. At least we will know if the problem related to settings.

Comment: Thanks Anton. It works with the settings removed! I think we need to add something in the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece works perfectly:

```
$tinymce_options = array(
'plugins' => "paste,lists,link,textcolor,hr,media,wordpress,wpeditimage,wpgallery,wpdialogs,wplink,wpview",
'wordpress_adv_hidden'=> false,
'toolbar1'=>"formatselect,fontsizeselect,forecolor,backcolor,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,alignjustify,wp_adv",
'toolbar2'=>"blockquote,hr,table,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,undo,redo,link,unlink,wp_fullscreen,wp_help"
);
```

Note I have added few wordpress related plugins in the tinymce options.

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out!)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `tinymce` option has a valid value. 
Remove it or set it to true if you don't pass any parameters to tinymce

```
$editor_config = array(
    'teeny'=>true,
    'textarea_rows'=>10, 
    'editor_class'=>'csec_text', 
    'textarea_name'=>'csec_body', 
    'wpautop'=>false, 
    'tinymce'=>$tinymce_options //THIS OPTION SHOULD BE VALID
);
```

**Edit:**
Made a small research. Add `wpview` in plugins argument of tinymce options.

```
$tinymce_options = array(
    'plugins' => "wpview,lists,link,textcolor,hr",
    //all other options
}
```

Also, there is no tinymce `table` plugin.
List of available plugins:

```
'charmap',
'colorpicker',
'hr',
'lists',
'media',
'paste',
'tabfocus',
'textcolor',
'fullscreen',
'wordpress',
'wpautoresize',
'wpeditimage',
'wpemoji',
'wpgallery',
'wplink',
'wpdialogs',
'wptextpattern',
'wpview',
```

Comment: teeny is already set to true. The $tinymce_options are also valid. I have updated the question with these options. Please check. The problem still persists.

Comment: Doing a little more r & d and it seems the $tinymce_options is the problem. Though it's valid, passing this parameter breaks the gallery amd image edit/delete format.

Comment: what options do you pass there

Comment: $tinymce_options = array('plugins' => "table,lists,link,textcolor,hr", 'toolbar1'=>"fontsizeselect,forecolor,backcolor,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,alignjustify",'toolbar2'=>"blockquote,hr,table,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link,unlink");

Comment: Check the question. I have updated with the full code.

Comment: #1. Including the 'wordpress' plugin removes all other custom buttons added (forces teeny editor)
#2. 'wpview' plugin shows thae gallery thumbnails, but noting happens on click.
#3. The 'table' plugin is working indeed. Omitting it removes the table button in the editor. In case the editor finds a wrong plugin name, it displays an error message.

Comment: Yeap, but this is out of scope of your question already)

Comment: The nearest functionality that I can reach (till now) is with my answer. Galleries in the MCE editor (with specific buttons as declared in the options) should be editable on click.

Comment: Finally... Check my answer. It works perfectly. Thanks you so much.